# Return the number of integers within the range of a and b that are divisible by x

Tags: divisibility

So I have a question here:

Return the number of integers within the range of *a* and *b* that are divisible by *x*.

So I have, *a = 0*, *b = 17* and *x = 17*.

Apparently the answer is *2*.

I understand that *17 / 17* is *1*, I just don't understand how *0 / 17* can count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0/17 = 0$  which is a perfectly good integer.

Comment: Ok thanks man for being very straight forward.